# What is happening when we integrate differentials?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, differential-forms

In Morris Tenenbaum's *Ordinary Differential Equation's* he introduces the concept of the differential of a function  $f(x)=y$ with the definition:

$$dy\left(x,\Delta x\right)=f'\left(x\right)\Delta x$$

He then treats $x$ as the identity map, to motivate replacing $\Delta x$ with $dx$, formalising why we write:

$$ dy=f'(x)dx$$

However, he then introduces seperable differential equations, which he writes as:
$$f(x)dx + g(y)dy = 0$$ treating $dx$ and $dy$ as differentials. At which point he asserts:

$$\int{f(x)dx}+\int{g(y)dy}=C$$

So what is happening here formally with regards to the original definiton of the differential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $dx,dy\ne0$ you can "divide" by them to give:
$$f(x)+g(y)y'=0$$ which seems more familiar. Furthermore, if we say that $y$ satisfies the equation $y=h(x)$ we get:
$$f(x)+gh(x)\cdot h'(x)=0$$

---

Note that in the equation:
$$f(x)dx+g(y)dy=0$$
$dx$ and $dy$ are not independent, since $y$ is a function of $x$ and so $dy$ is a function of $dx$